# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{}],"original":"ERROR:: AAPT: D:\android-basics-kotlin-cupcake-app-starter\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\out\resources-debug.ap_: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).\nerror: failed to create archive.\n\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:: AAPT: D:\android-basics-kotlin-cupcake-app-starter\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\out\resources-debug.ap_: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
> error: failed to create archive.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
27 actionable tasks: 26 executed, 1 up-to-date

Can anyone help me to solve this problem...? please...

Comment: Try updating your `build.tools` verison.

Comment: I have tried it. But it did not work for me. And i cannot find "D:\\androidProject\\android-basics-kotlin-cupcake-app-starter\\app\\build\\intermediates\\processed_res\\debug\\out\\resources-debug.ap_"  this file in my directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when `aapt` fails to create an archive.

First make sure you are using the latest IDE and SDK. `aapt` for packaging is obsolete, and the earlier `aapt2` has many bugs.

If they are up to date, try to check if the following processes on your computer have read/write access to the project directory.

- [your android sdk path]\build-tools[your sdk version]\aapt.exe
- [your android sdk path]\build-tools[your sdk version]\aapt2.exe
- [your android studio path]\bin\studio64.exe
- [your android studio path]\bin\fsnotifier64.exe
- [your android studio path]\jre\bin\java.exe
- [your android studio path]\jre\bin\javaw.exe

If you haven't set permissions manually, they are usually blocked by security software.
I recently ran into this problem and spent a lot of time finally found out that the security software on my workstation was not adding `aapt2` and `aapt` to the allowed list for the project repository.